# Opengl Superbible Configuring an IDE

Tags: c++, opengl, configuration, cmake, kdevelop4

Someone knows how to configure Kdevelop and cmakelist.txt to work with GLTools/GLU/ and other opengl libraries?

Opengl superbible brings a tutorial to configure VS and a MAC IDE, but, i can't find any tutorial to configure Kdevelop to work fine with superbible's libs...

Comment: does KDevelop still use a "make" based building?

Comment: It uses cmake and supports old make, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the configuration is in CMakeLists.txt moreso than KDevelop, which is told what to do by the CMake manager. That said, google turned up a few points of interest regarding opengl config with CMake. These look like they have the main points of interest:

http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-February/027234.html

http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-February/027330.html

Basically just:

```
find_package(OpenGL)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(targetname ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```